# Advantages/Disadvantages between Murex v.s. Radzyn Tekhelet

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles

What halachic advantages are there in purchasing tekhelet strings dyed by the murex snail as opposed to tekhelet strings dyed by the cuttlefish?

Are Radziner cuttlefish-dyed strings acceptable?

Comment: Murex dye is steadfast,the Murex has a reason why we couldnt use it,while the cuttlefish was always around and wasnt banned by the Roman govt,The murex is mentioned by Rishonim and Achronim,The Murex actually produces a blue day after exposure to the light without chemical manipulation, and has a black hue as the Rambam mentions, these are to name a few

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75257/arguments-for-radzyner-techeiles/75278#75278

Comment: The advantage of murex is it's kosher according to many, many, many, many more people. (Almost no one thinks cuttlefish is Kosher, and those that do are generally disregarded by everyone else.) I don't know what else you are expecting anyone to say here.

Comment: There is now (~Sep. 2018) a document your on this you may want to consider watching.

Answer (score -1):

That question is answered very well on 
YouTube "Radziner Vs. Murex Tekheleth, The Truth!".
Murex is Argaman not techalet. Buy the cheaper and go Darg or cuttlefish. A snail is not a fish or does not swim or have fins.
So the Radzinger version is obviously right, but watch the Youtube.
This is a good comparison. 
http://www.techelet.info/chilazon-comparison/

This video presents the results of many years of unbiased research by Mori (Rabbi) Michael S. Bar-Ron, championing the kashruth of Radziner tekheleth over Murex tekheleth (Argaman).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKhbhTkrGtQ

Comment: this is a very poor answer, I could easily say that it is better to go with a blue dye then to go with cuttlefish dye which needs enahnchers to turn blue,this answer also provides no facts just unsourced rhetoric

Comment: "A snail is not a fish." Really? How do you know that? Is it not Sheretz HaYam just like a squid is?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe it is the Shita of Rav Ovadia M'Barentura who holds that the Chilazon is a Sheretz HaMayim. Where did you get the idea that the cuttlefish bears the criteria of being a Sheretz as well?

Comment: **ושאר שקצים ורמשים- כגון תולעים וחלזונות ועקרבים, החובל בהם פטור, דאין להם עור** - From Shabbos 14:1

Comment: This is a very weak answer. The question sought _advantages_ of Murex and whether cuttlefish is (nonetheless) kosher. This answer gives disadvantages of Murex and uses them to conclude that cuttlefish is kosher (a curious conclusion anyway and which barely answers the question).

Comment: @RoshHaYeshiveh I don't mean to be rude. I'm literally flabbergasted so I indicated as much. Perhaps you can explain to me why I shouldn't be flabbergasted that people still believe an animal with no unique properties/components/elements for making a blue dye is still considered to be the ancient dye source sought. How can something be the ancient blue dye source when it isn't a blue dye source??

Comment: @msh210 Please see my second comment to the other answer, which seems to be even less of an answer than this.

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my understanding there is archaeological evidence proving the use of the murex trunculus as an ancient dye, particularly in Israel, because of an ancient murex-dyeing site unearthed near the Temple Mount and an ancient textiled that contains a murex-dyed blue stripe found near Masada.

I need a source for this also (can someone help out) but I seem to recall a Gemara or something that mentions the Romans outlawed the use of techeiles by anyone but royalty, and the Romans commonly used the murex trunculus snail, not the cuttlefish, to dye blue clothing.

Like everyone else who has answered this question, I strongly recommend watching this YouTube video explaining why the Radziner-cuttlefish method for dyeing techeiles is more authentic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKhbhTkrGtQ&spfreload=10

And, truth be told, it could very well be that cuttlefish and murex snails are both not the chilazon.

But there is sufficient proof that the cuttlefish is the chilazon, and if you honestly believe that then Radziner techeiles is perfectly acceptable for you.

Comment: Someone to help out with the sources would be great.

Comment: "Like everyone else who has answered this question" Do you mean like the one other guy who answered this question and was strongly downvoted? I for one do not recommend your average starting-to-inquire person watch that video. The fact that it's long and has lots of text doesn't make it more authoritative.

Comment: I'm confused how this answers the question... "What halachic advantages are there"? You haven't listed any. The only thing I see here is an answer to "Are Radziner cuttlefish-dyed strings acceptable?" which is "if you honestly believe that then Radziner techeiles is perfectly acceptable for you" which is fascinatingly post-modern (and unsourced) conclusion.